# Wordpress echo or get the single post title except the last 6 characters

Tags: wordpress, post, title, trim

is there any way to echo or get the wordpress single post title EXCEPT last 6 characters?
Or maybe trimming the last 6 characters of the post title.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following snippet of code inside of your template or inside of the single view.

```
<?php echo substr( get_the_title(), 0, -6 ); ?>
```

References:

- [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)
- [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)